# Trouble Restoring MYSQL Database on CentOS Using SSH

Tags: mysql, centos6

I just had to change [dedicated CentOs] servers at Godaddy.

After I uploaded my `.sql` database backup file to the site using FTP, I connected to my site using SSH.

After changing to super user using the su - command, i tried using the following code to restore my database:

`[root@sXXX.XXX.XXX.XXX ~]# mysql -u alaskasl_destiny -p alaskasl_freakout < /home/alaskasl/backup/databases/alaskasl_freakout.sql`

I get the following `ERROR 1044 (42000): Access denied for user 'alaskasl_destiny'@'localhost' to database 'alaskasl_freakout'`

I can't figure out what I am doing wrong. This command has always worked for me in the past

Answer (score 0):

First and foremost, if alasas1... is your real username, I would replace it with 'username'.  Never give that info out, especially on a public place like Stackoverflow.

That said, a few things to check
1. You need to know the root user's login credentials for this new mysql instance.  If this is a new setup the user is root with no password, so you should be able to use the following command:

```
$ mysql -u root
```

2. Once you do get in to mysql, you will see a prompt similar to:
   mysql>
   at that prompt you can type

   mysql> show databases;

and a list of databases will display.  Does the database you expect to be in there in there?

if not, here is what you need to do:

```
mysql> CREATE DATABASE 'database_name';
mysql> CREATE USER 'username' IDENTIFIED BY 'password';
mysql> GRANT ALL PRIVILEGES ON *.database_name TO 'username';
mysql> exit
```

At this point what you did was create the database, create a user with a password in mysql, and granted access to that database for that user.  Once you type exit, you should now be back at the command prompt.

Now you can run `mysql -u username -p database_name < /path/to/sql_file.sql`

Comment: Thanks for your help, my friend. I really appreciate your advice and your answer. It gave me everything I needed to get my database restored. You are awesome! Stack overflow should make a Virtual Tip Jar, so folks like me can send you a gratuity on PayPal.

Comment: No problem!  We have all been there, me definitely.  Just passing on what I have learned.  I don't expect gratuity, but if you can mark this answer as the correct answer, that would be great! Have a great day!